# Http request is returning 401

Tags: android, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

In my project I an calling a webservice to get json response the request will need a username and password to authenticate. I have passed the username and password in the header in the header. But the request is returning 401 response which means the credentials are incorrect.

Here is my code.

```
String path = "http://example.com/mobile/GetMenuByCategoryId/3";
        try {
            String username = "usrename", password = "password";
            String joined = username + ":" + password;
            String authSring = "Basic "+Base64.encode(joined.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authSring);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 200){
                InputStream is= connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                int line = 0;
                while((line = br.read())!=-1){
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE", "response = \n "+ sb.toString() );
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Post your server side code.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to that. Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Your code looks okay. It seems the authorization fails.

Comment: You sure you need to base64 encode your auth string? Double check that it is in accordance of the server requirements. My bet is that the issue lies there

Comment: I've tried both, with authentication and without authentication

Comment: What does the server specs/documentation say? If there is no info on authentication, you need to contact the service provider and ask them what is the correct format. And also you are 100% sure that username and password are correct?

Comment: Yes that is 100% sure, username and password are correct